# Will all event pages load with only one event?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have my code separated in many js files, working together.  I have one background.js alone, listening to a pageAction's click.  The click opens in a new windows the extension's HTML document that load my other scripts, with < script > tags.

I want to eliminate the HTML document, and run the scripts in background.

If I convert all those scripts into event page' scripts (i.e. background pages with persistent:false), will them load with pageAction's click?

Do a single listener in only one event page script file open all other event pages scripts files?  Or have every single js file to have their own same listener?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I turned every script into event page, and they work as expected.  The whole group is executed when one listener is called.

In manifest:

```
"background":{"scripts":["script1", "script2", ...], "persistent":false}
```